# Angular 2 - subscribing to Observable.fromEvent error: "Invalid event target"

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am getting a weird error when trying to subscribe to an Observable.

Here is a watered down version of the code which presents the problem:

```js
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'action-overview-description',
  template: require('./actionOverviewDescription.html')
})
export class ActionOverviewDescription  {
  @ViewChild('button') button;

  constructor() {}
  
   ngOnInit() {

    let buttonStream$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(this.button, 'click')
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

  }
}
```

```html
<button #input>Button</button>
```

The error I get in the console is:

> Invalid event target

The error ONLY shows up when I subscribe to the stream. If I only create it but don't subscribe, there is no error. If I console.log the stream it seems to have a subscribe member.

I have tried googling the error but I can't seem to find anywhere it's explained.

I think I'm using Rxjs 4.0.5 (according to npm rxjs --version).

Comment: Can you show us your html code as well?

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: I'm tried ngAfterViewInit. It doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there any particular part of the HTML you want to see? The template is simplified down to "<button #input>Button</button>"

Comment: Is it loaded a template? does it have errors in it?

Comment: `@ViewChild('button')` should be `ViewChild('input')`.

Comment: See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122040/234110) answer - this is what eventually worked for me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The problem is the lifecycle hook you're using. The element is not yet creating in DOM when `ngOnInit` is called. Instead, you should use `ngAfterViewInit`.

Could you try the following code:

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  template: '<button #input>Button</button>'
})
export class ActionOverviewDescription implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('input') button: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let buttonStream$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

  }
}
```

Comment: Okay after fiddling around for a while it now works! I think the error may be in the way I imported the Rxjs-stuff. Maybe the missing "import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent'. It's just a rather undescriptive error message if that's the case. I also was under the impression ElementRef was deprecated or something... in any event - it now works! Thank you to AngularFrance for the answer.

Comment: Ok, good. :) ElementRef is [marked as stable in the API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html), I don't think it's deprecated. Anyways it's just a type annotation. You could replace it with `any` and the code would work just the same. FYI, I think the main error in your code was targeting `this.button` vs `this.button.nativeElement`.

Comment: This would not work for me. I ended up defining button as type : any, then used Observable.fromEvent(this.button._elementRef.nativeElement  , 'click') - I was using within the context of an Ionic 3 project. It uses Angular 4 under the covers/..

Comment: That's because your button was probably of type `MatButton`, @JGFMK, or something similar, not `ElementRef`

Comment: Btw, ViewChild will always be available in ngOnInit(). You only need afterViewInit for Viewchildren, and a ViewChild that's in *ngFor, ngIf or ng-template. In the source code of Angular ViewChild is considered "static" and has to be available before ngOnInit is called (search for "ViewChild static ngOnInit") https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21800#issuecomment-360799520

Comment: Just to elaborate on Drenai's comment:  `@ViewChild('input', {'static': true}) button: ElementRef;` would ensure it to be static.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access it in `ngOnInit` event then you would have to use `{ static: true }` property of `ViewChild` something like this:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  template: '<button #input>Button</button>'
})
export class ActionOverviewDescription implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('input', { static: true }) button: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    let buttonStream$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));

  }
}
```

Comment: I was struggling with attaching to a div's scroll event in ngOnInit. This working example helped me get there. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)