# debounceTime to CodeMirror Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, codemirror

I have already tried multiple variations also following [This Possible Dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454740/angular-2-subscribing-to-observable-fromevent-error-invalid-event-target)

Using the `ng2-codemirror 1.1.3` lib + `codemirror 5.33.0` anchor

All I'm trying to do is to attach a DebounceTime operator to the `change` event of the CodeMirror Editor

html:

```
<codemirror #cm [(ngModel)]="code" [config]="config" (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()"></codemirror>
```

ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@ViewChild('cm') editor;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const watch = Observable.fromEvent(this.editor, 'change'); // <--- Error
  watch.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target

I've also tried attaching the `Observable.fromEvent` to `this.editor.value`/ `this.editor.input`

**EDIT** 
Entire Component:
component.HTML:

```
<codemirror #cm [(ngModel)]="code" [config]="config" (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()"></codemirror>
```

component.TS:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { global } from '../shared/global.constants';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
import 'codemirror/addon/scroll/simplescrollbars';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/javascript-hint';
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('cm') editor;
  @ViewChild('output') output;
  code = global.code;
  config = {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: {name: 'javascript', json: true},
    tabSize: 2,
    scrollbarStyle: 'simple',
    extraKeys: {'Tab': 'autocomplete', 'Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete'}
  };

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.editor); // <--- CodemirrorComponent {change: EventEmitter, focus: EventEmitter, blur: EventEmitter, cursorActivity: EventEmitter, instance: CodeMirror$1, …}
    console.log(this.editor.nativeElement); // <--- undefined
    const watch = Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.host.nativeElement, 'input');
    console.log(watch);
    watch.subscribe(w => console.log(w)); // <-- invalid target
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that `<codemirror>` is a component, `@ViewChild('cm') editor` queries an instance of component class, while `@ViewChild('cm') editor: ElementRef` just tricks typing system but doesn't affect `editor` value.

As [the reference](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) explains, `read` property is used to specify which token should be queried. In order to force it to be `ElementRef`, it should be:

```
@ViewChild('cm', { read: ElementRef }) editor: ElementRef;
```

Then event listener can be added to DOM element (as another answer already explains):

```
const watch = Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.nativeElement, 'change');
```

Comment: `const watch = Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.nativeElement, 'input');
    watch.debounceTime(200).subscribe(e => {
      console.log(this.editor.nativeElement.innerText);
    });`

Works - fantastic!! thank you and @PankajParkar so much!!!

Comment: This is an interesting. I'll investigate more on this, thanks @estus for pointing this out.

Comment: You're welcome. @PankajParkar Sure. IIRC, by default string query (template variable name) returns ElementRef for regular elements and directives but class instance for components, so it's a good practice to use explicit `read` whenever possible.

Comment: Does this have solution for vanilla js? I am not from Angular, I am not able to grasp it. Can someone explain?

Comment: @Rehan Both the question and the answer are very specific to ng2-codemirror and not CodeMirror in general. RxJS Observable is not exclusive to Angular but is used here because they work well together, you may not need it for vanilla JS. I'd suggest to ask a new question that explains your problem in detail.

Comment: Sure, I have opened up a question regarding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62157612/debouncing-codemirror-input-on-change-event Can you check? Thanks @EstusFlask

Answer (score 3):

Passon element (`nativeElement`) to [**`Observable.fromEvent`**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md#rxobservablefromeventelement-eventname-selector-options) method.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const watch = Observable.fromEvent(this.editor.nativeElement, 'change');
  watch.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
}
```

Comment: Hey. Tried, still same error. even went ahead and added `@ViewChild('cm') editor: ElementRef;` as shows in the link I attached

Comment: @estus. I understand :)
Please see the edit - I added logs (`this.editor.nativeElement` returns `undefined`)

Comment: @OmerShukar It says nothing on what `this.editor` equals to. The question doesn't contain the entire component, only snippets, so it's not obvious that `#cm` is really in component template. There may be a mistake on your side, that's why http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is essential in trouble-solving questions.

Comment: @estus Added entire component

Comment: @OmerShukar does `#cm` / `codemirror` belongs to `main.component.html`??

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes!