# Error when upgrading Angular material to v5.0.0

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I upgraded to Angular 5 around the time it was released and haven't had an problems with my code base, but was never able to upgrade Angular Material past beta.11... This is the error I am getting in node:

```
ERROR { TypeError: Invalid event target
    at Function.FromEventObservable.setupSubscription (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.js:189:19)
    at FromEventObservable._subscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/observable/FromEventObservable.js:211:29)
    at FromEventObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:172:25)
    at FromEventObservable.Observable.subscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:160:65)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/util/subscribeToResult.js:23:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js:132:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js:129:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js:112:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:89:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable.js:114:28)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:172:25)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:160:65)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/operators/mergeMap.js:87:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:157:22)
    at AuditOperator.call (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/operators/audit.js:62:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/lsorensen/code/OneUnionV1/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:157:22)
  ngDebugContext:
   DebugContext_ {
     view:
      { def: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        viewContainerParent: null,
        parentNodeDef: [Object],
        context: [Object],
        component: [Object],
        nodes: [Array],
        state: 13,
        root: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        oldValues: [Array],
        disposables: [Array] },
     nodeIndex: 4,
     nodeDef:
      { nodeIndex: 4,
        parent: [Object],
        renderParent: [Object],
        bindingIndex: 0,
        outputIndex: 1,
        checkIndex: 4,
        flags: 114688,
        childFlags: 0,
        directChildFlags: 0,
        childMatchedQueries: 0,
        matchedQueries: [Object],
        matchedQueryIds: 4,
        references: {},
        ngContentIndex: -1,
        childCount: 0,
        bindings: [Array],
        bindingFlags: 8,
        outputs: [Array],
        element: null,
        provider: [Object],
        text: null,
        query: null,
        ngContent: null },
     elDef:
      { nodeIndex: 3,
        parent: null,
        renderParent: null,
        bindingIndex: 0,
        outputIndex: 0,
        checkIndex: 3,
        flags: 33554433,
        childFlags: 114690,
        directChildFlags: 114690,
        childMatchedQueries: 4,
        matchedQueries: {},
        matchedQueryIds: 0,
        references: {},
        ngContentIndex: null,
        childCount: 2,
        bindings: [],
        bindingFlags: 0,
        outputs: [Array],
        element: [Object],
        provider: null,
        text: null,
        query: null,
        ngContent: null },
     elView:
      { def: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        viewContainerParent: null,
        parentNodeDef: [Object],
        context: [Object],
        component: [Object],
        nodes: [Array],
        state: 13,
        root: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        oldValues: [Array],
        disposables: [Array] } },
  ngErrorLogger: [Function: bound ],
  __zone_symbol__currentTask:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: undefined,
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {
  view:
   { def:
      { factory: [Object],
        nodeFlags: 1061404723,
        rootNodeFlags: 436207619,
        nodeMatchedQueries: 6,
        flags: 0,
        nodes: [Array],
        updateDirectives: [Function],
        updateRenderer: [Function],
        handleEvent: [Function: handleEvent],
        bindingCount: 10,
        outputCount: 5,
        lastRenderRootNode: [Object] },
     parent:
      { def: [Object],
        parent: null,
        viewContainerParent: null,
        parentNodeDef: null,
        context: {},
        component: {},
        nodes: [Array],
        state: 13,
        root: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        oldValues: [],
        disposables: null },
     viewContainerParent: null,
     parentNodeDef:
      { nodeIndex: 1,
        parent: [Object],
        renderParent: [Object],
        bindingIndex: 0,
        outputIndex: 0,
        checkIndex: 1,
        flags: 114688,
        childFlags: 0,
        directChildFlags: 0,
        childMatchedQueries: 0,
        matchedQueries: {},
        matchedQueryIds: 0,
        references: {},
        ngContentIndex: -1,
        childCount: 0,
        bindings: [],
        bindingFlags: 0,
        outputs: [],
        element: null,
        provider: [Object],
        text: null,
        query: null,
        ngContent: null },
     context:
      AppComponent {
        cache: [Object],
        _dialogService: DialogService {},
        _identityService: [Object],
        _facebookService: FacebookService {},
        _updateHeaderService: [Object],
        router: [Object],
        route: [Object],
        loc: [Object],
        loading: true,
        isSidenavActive: false,
        siteTitle: '1Union',
        routeLabel: '1Union',
        isLoggedIn: [Object] },
     component:
      AppComponent {
        cache: [Object],
        _dialogService: DialogService {},
        _identityService: [Object],
        _facebookService: FacebookService {},
        _updateHeaderService: [Object],
        router: [Object],
        route: [Object],
        loc: [Object],
        loading: true,
        isSidenavActive: false,
        siteTitle: '1Union',
        routeLabel: '1Union',
        isLoggedIn: [Object] },
     nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], <57 empty items> ],
     state: 13,
     root:
      { ngModule: [Object],
        injector: _NullInjector {},
        projectableNodes: [],
        selectorOrNode: 'ou-app',
        sanitizer: [Object],
        rendererFactory: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        errorHandler: [Object] },
     renderer: DebugRenderer2 { delegate: [Object] },
     oldValues: [ <10 empty items> ],
     disposables: [ [Function], <4 empty items> ] },
  nodeIndex: 4,
  nodeDef:
   { nodeIndex: 4,
     parent:
      { nodeIndex: 3,
        parent: null,
        renderParent: null,
        bindingIndex: 0,
        outputIndex: 0,
        checkIndex: 3,
        flags: 33554433,
        childFlags: 114690,
        directChildFlags: 114690,
        childMatchedQueries: 4,
        matchedQueries: {},
        matchedQueryIds: 0,
        references: {},
        ngContentIndex: null,
        childCount: 2,
        bindings: [],
        bindingFlags: 0,
        outputs: [Array],
        element: [Object],
        provider: null,
        text: null,
        query: null,
        ngContent: null },
     renderParent:
      { nodeIndex: 3,
        parent: null,
        renderParent: null,
        bindingIndex: 0,
        outputIndex: 0,
        checkIndex: 3,
        flags: 33554433,
        childFlags: 114690,
        directChildFlags: 114690,
        childMatchedQueries: 4,
        matchedQueries: {},
        matchedQueryIds: 0,
        references: {},
        ngContentIndex: null,
        childCount: 2,
        bindings: [],
        bindingFlags: 0,
        outputs: [Array],
        element: [Object],
        provider: null,
        text: null,
        query: null,
        ngContent: null },
     bindingIndex: 0,
     outputIndex: 1,
     checkIndex: 4,
     flags: 114688,
     childFlags: 0,
     directChildFlags: 0,
     childMatchedQueries: 0,
     matchedQueries: { '2': 4 },
     matchedQueryIds: 4,
     references: {},
     ngContentIndex: -1,
     childCount: 0,
     bindings: [ [Object] ],
     bindingFlags: 8,
     outputs: [ [Object] ],
     element: null,
     provider:
      { token: [Function: SidenavComponent],
        value: [Function: SidenavComponent],
        deps: [Array] },
     text: null,
     query: null,
     ngContent: null },
  elDef:
   { nodeIndex: 3,
     parent: null,
     renderParent: null,
     bindingIndex: 0,
     outputIndex: 0,
     checkIndex: 3,
     flags: 33554433,
     childFlags: 114690,
     directChildFlags: 114690,
     childMatchedQueries: 4,
     matchedQueries: {},
     matchedQueryIds: 0,
     references: {},
     ngContentIndex: null,
     childCount: 2,
     bindings: [],
     bindingFlags: 0,
     outputs: [ [Object] ],
     element:
      { ns: '',
        name: 'sidenav',
        attrs: [],
        template: null,
        componentProvider: [Object],
        componentView: [Object],
        componentRendererType: [Object],
        publicProviders: [Object],
        allProviders: [Object],
        handleEvent: [Function] },
     provider: null,
     text: null,
     query: null,
     ngContent: null },
  elView:
   { def:
      { factory: [Object],
        nodeFlags: 1061404723,
        rootNodeFlags: 436207619,
        nodeMatchedQueries: 6,
        flags: 0,
        nodes: [Array],
        updateDirectives: [Function],
        updateRenderer: [Function],
        handleEvent: [Function: handleEvent],
        bindingCount: 10,
        outputCount: 5,
        lastRenderRootNode: [Object] },
     parent:
      { def: [Object],
        parent: null,
        viewContainerParent: null,
        parentNodeDef: null,
        context: {},
        component: {},
        nodes: [Array],
        state: 13,
        root: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        oldValues: [],
        disposables: null },
     viewContainerParent: null,
     parentNodeDef:
      { nodeIndex: 1,
        parent: [Object],
        renderParent: [Object],
        bindingIndex: 0,
        outputIndex: 0,
        checkIndex: 1,
        flags: 114688,
        childFlags: 0,
        directChildFlags: 0,
        childMatchedQueries: 0,
        matchedQueries: {},
        matchedQueryIds: 0,
        references: {},
        ngContentIndex: -1,
        childCount: 0,
        bindings: [],
        bindingFlags: 0,
        outputs: [],
        element: null,
        provider: [Object],
        text: null,
        query: null,
        ngContent: null },
     context:
      AppComponent {
        cache: [Object],
        _dialogService: DialogService {},
        _identityService: [Object],
        _facebookService: FacebookService {},
        _updateHeaderService: [Object],
        router: [Object],
        route: [Object],
        loc: [Object],
        loading: true,
        isSidenavActive: false,
        siteTitle: '1Union',
        routeLabel: '1Union',
        isLoggedIn: [Object] },
     component:
      AppComponent {
        cache: [Object],
        _dialogService: DialogService {},
        _identityService: [Object],
        _facebookService: FacebookService {},
        _updateHeaderService: [Object],
        router: [Object],
        route: [Object],
        loc: [Object],
        loading: true,
        isSidenavActive: false,
        siteTitle: '1Union',
        routeLabel: '1Union',
        isLoggedIn: [Object] },
     nodes: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], <57 empty items> ],
     state: 13,
     root:
      { ngModule: [Object],
        injector: _NullInjector {},
        projectableNodes: [],
        selectorOrNode: 'ou-app',
        sanitizer: [Object],
        rendererFactory: [Object],
        renderer: [Object],
        errorHandler: [Object] },
     renderer: DebugRenderer2 { delegate: [Object] },
     oldValues: [ <10 empty items> ],
     disposables: [ [Function], <4 empty items> ] } }
```

Here is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "TheOneUnion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && npm run server",
    "build": "webpack --progress --color",
    "build:aot": "webpack --env.aot --env.client & webpack --env.aot --env.server",
    "build:prod": "webpack --env.aot --env.client -p & webpack --env.aot --env.server",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "prebuild:aot": "npm run clean",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "server": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "watch:dev": "npm run server & npm run watch",
    "debug:server": "node-nightly --inspect --debug-brk dist/server.js & webpack --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/mongodb": "2.2.15",
    "angular2-jwt": "0.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.7",
    "aws-sdk": "2.154.0",
    "base64url": "2.0.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "1.18.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "compression": "1.7.1",
    "crypto": "1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "css-to-string-loader": "0.1.3",
    "debug": "2.6.9",
    "elasticsearch": "12.1.3",
    "evaporate": "2.1.4",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "express-engine": "1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "global": "4.3.2",
    "gm": "1.23.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "html-metadata": "1.6.3",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "js.clone": "0.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.4.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "log4js": "1.1.1",
    "methods": "1.1.2",
    "minilog": "3.1.0",
    "moment": "2.19.2",
    "mongoose": "4.13.4",
    "morgan": "1.9.0",
    "ng2-facebook-sdk": "2.3.1",
    "node-ffprobe": "1.2.2",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "nodemailer": "4.4.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "request": "2.83.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "webfontloader": "1.6.28",
    "xhr2": "0.1.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.3",
    "@types/angular-material": "1.1.58",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "0.0.42",
    "@types/base64url": "2.0.3",
    "@types/bluebird": "3.5.18",
    "@types/body-parser": "0.0.34",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.33",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "1.4.1",
    "@types/elasticsearch": "5.0.17",
    "@types/evaporate": "0.0.18",
    "@types/express": "4.0.39",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.0.57",
    "@types/gm": "1.17.33",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "7.2.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.85",
    "@types/mime": "0.0.29",
    "@types/mongoose": "4.7.27",
    "@types/morgan": "1.7.35",
    "@types/node": "7.0.48",
    "@types/nodemailer": "1.3.33",
    "@types/request": "2.0.8",
    "@types/serve-static": "1.13.1",
    "@types/webfontloader": "1.6.29",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "node-loader": "0.6.0",
    "nodemon": "1.12.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "1.8.8",
    "typescript": "2.5.1",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0"
  }
}
```

If anyone has any bit of an idea of where to start or look it would help me out a lot. let me know if you need more information.. thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a dependency version mismatch - probably with rxjs. It might be a good idea to check which version of rxjs is actually installed and make sure it is compatible with the Angular and Angular Material versions installed. Your package.json specifies Angular 5.0.2 and Angular Material 5.2.4, but for material 5.2.4 you should be using Angular 5.2.3+ and rxjs 5.5.5+. The point is, make sure everything you have installed works together.

Comment: I tried using Material 5.0.0 and 5.0.2 first before 5.2.3 and got the same error

Comment: I think it might be the way I set up angular universal when angular was still in v2

Comment: What is your version of rxjs?

Comment: 5.5.6... I also tried 5.5.2

Comment: When are you subscribing to Observables? This may be a timing issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454740/angular-2-subscribing-to-observable-fromevent-error-invalid-event-target).